# Create new array inside a multidimensional array, step up name each cycle

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Question:

How can I iterate below so it checks existence of key "round_1", next script run it should check existense of key "round_2", etc. Everytime it would encounter that the key is missing it should create the key.

It is working with "round_1" as expected.

```
<?php

// Create array skeleton.

$array_skeleton = array_fill(1, 3, "");

print_r($array_skeleton);

// Populate the skeleton with random numbers, values [1 to 6].

foreach($array_skeleton as $key => $value) {
    $populated_array[$key] = random_int(1, 6);
};

print_r($populated_array);

// Create empty array for purpose to become multidimensional array.

$scorecard = [];

// Check if [round_1] is missing, if so create [round_1] and populate it.

if(!array_key_exists("round_1", $scorecard)) {
    echo "round_1 is missing, creating it";
    $scorecard["round_1"] = $populated_array;
}

print_r($scorecard);
```

**Outcome works fine as expected, after first script run:**

```
(
    [round_1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 1
        )

)
```

**Expected outcome, after second script run:**
Note! It is correct that the values would be different per each round since they are randomly created.

```
(
    [round_1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 1
        )
     [round_2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: If you create the `$scorecard` each time how can you know which keys it has or on which run number are you at?

Comment: @dWinder That is a correct observation. The $scorecard should only be created the first round of running the script. Potentially I have to store the value in a $_SESSION for it to survive during each run of script.

Comment: @Andreas I plan to use the structure in later stage from a browser, thus perform the savings in $_POST and potentially move them to $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your entire code can be simplify:

first define function for create array with random number:

```
function createRandomNumberArray($numOfElem, $maxRange) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfElem; $i++)
        $res[] = random_int(1, $maxRange);
    return $res;
}
```

Second, assuming your keys are made of "round_@INT@" pattern you can do

```
$biggest = max(array_map(function ($e) {$p = explode("_", $e); return $p[1];}, array_keys($arr)));
```

And now do:

```
$newKey = "round_" . ($biggest + 1);
$scorecard[$newKey] = createRandomNumberArray(3,6);
```

Reference: [array-map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [explode](https://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [max](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php), [random-int](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php)